# How to save I/O Graphs with Tshark in csv?

Tags: csv, wireshark, tshark

Please, help me. I don't know how to save I/O Graphs(Packets/time) with Tshark in csv? Like this:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Capture data by the tshark to a file: `tshark -i <interface_name> -s 0 -w <path_and_file_name>`
2. Transfer the data to any computer where the Wireshark is installed.
3. Open the data file by the Wireshark.
4. Display the I/O graph: Main menu -> Statistics -> I/O Graphs
5. Carefully adjust the units of the X (seconds) and Y (bits or bytes) axes of the graph.
6. Save the graph in CSV format: Save as -> Comma Separated Values

You get a CSV file in which the first column is the time and the second is the value of the data flow.

[image: CSV data in the text editor]

[image: CSV data in the Libreoffice Calc]